# BBCode parser without Regex?

Tags: php, javascript, parsing, bbcode

I'm looking for a BBCode parser in Javascript or PHP without the need of using Regex. Can anybody suggest me a good one?

Comment: why are you avoiding regex?  (speed?)

Comment: Because I don't just want to replace the tags, I also want to do a little bit with the content between the tags. Do you have any suggestion for me?

Comment: "I also want to do a little bit with the content between the tags"  `preg_replace_callback()` is great for this.  If you can give us a solid example of what exactly you're trying to do, we can give you more specific advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is recommended to use regex.

Other solution:

```
function bb_parse($str)
{
    return str_replace(array('[b]', '[/b]'), array('<strong>', '</strong>'), $str);
}
```

This can break parsing due to mis-closing tags can end up content being wrapped with a HTML tag without closing.

Comment: Ehm, BB is a recursive format just as HTML. Thus, I invoke the pony: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2):

There's a [PECL extension for bbcode](https://www.php.net/bbcode). You'll need to take a look on [how to install PECL extensions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php) in order to utilize it.

Comment: I believe the PECL extension segfaulted on several of my tests, so proceed with caution.

Answer (score 1):

Zend parser might be what you're looking for http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.markup.parsers.html

Unfortunately, I found it the least practically functional of the BBCode parsers I evaluated: when encountering malformed markup (`[b] asdf [/   wops I forgot to close my tag`) it tends to throw away all content after the first malformed tag.  Other bbcode parsers do a much better job of simply ignoring bad markup.

Answer (score 0):

So I know you said no regex, but I recently wrote a BBCode parser in JavaScript, and I believe it addresses your concerns since it is **not** a simple find and replace and it gives you access to the content within the tags. You can see a demo of it here:

http://patorjk.com/bbcode-previewer/

And get the source and write up on it here:

http://patorjk.com/blog/2011/05/07/extendible-bbcode-parser-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

I recently write a bbcode parser in javascript.

What it can do:

1. Convert BBcode string to HTML string;
2. Convert HTML element to BBCode string;
3. Auto correct BBCode string;

Check the demo: [UBBParser](http://zmmbreeze.github.com/UBBParser/)

Answer (score -1):

If you can install a PECL extension, you will be able to use the [BBCode functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bbcode.php)